# Select columns which match value of a column in same table in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, data-wrangling

Dataset:

A Pyspark dataframe with 200+ columns, where 10 columns have distinct name and the rest have a common prefix and suffix name (F_lag,B_lag,R_lag.... F_lag10,B_lag10,R_lag10)
and condition column called as MAX (please see picture below)

### Goal:
I need to create a new dataframe which contains the 10 distinct column and select all the columns which match the suffix/prefix value of MAX

Scenarios:
For each row the MAX value changes, so the column which need to be selected change
We can create a new column with standard name and fill the value of the matched column

[Input and expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g8Hx.png)

Comment: Show us something that you have tried.

Comment: I wish, I could but I’m completely stuck at this . I tried creating a lambda function which could create new column for every combination, meaning, create new column for F_lag1 to F_lag10 but that didn’t just work